# the browser wont reload automatic,but will once I click somewhere,eg, the browser irself

Tags: web, gulp, browser-sync

This is weird to get this problem, and after some search, I cant fix this problem, This is my first time to ask something on stackoverflow. my gulpfile.js following...

```
//I just want an easy task,once the css change,reload the browser.
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
gulp.task('watch',['browserSync'], function() {
      gulp.watch('src/css/*.css', browserSycn.reload);
      gulp.watch('src/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
      browserSync({
           server: {
              baseDir: 'src'
              }
        })
    });
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Baudin ubuntu 14.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
```

And use

```
browserSync.**init**({
       server: {
          baseDir: 'src'
          }
    })
```

To initialize. Hope this helps.

EDIT 17 jan 2016: WebStorm can sometimes seem to cache the change and not write it to the file system. In this case browserSync (gulp) can't see the change. Clicking out of WebStorm or refreshing will force the update. This seems to be your problem.

Comment: thanks,but the problem still there, only after clicking the browser, reload happended.

Comment: After hours of trying...what ide are you using? If webstorm, could you try something simple like vi. Found issues with webstorm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, yeah, I also tried hours to fix this, but problem still, but once I try some simple eiditor like vim or sublime,problem still happens. Thanks again!

Comment: I do some try again, after I save the change by myself, the vim, editor,and also including the webstorm, browser reload! so, maybe this is a bug of webstorm?

Comment: Hi, yes, WebStorm seems to cache changes in some way. There is a menu option called "Synchronise with FileSystem" which pushes the change. You can also close and open a folder in WebStorm to refresh. Using something like vim or a simple text editor will change the file immediately and trigger the browserSync refresh of the page.